# Creating Duplicate Table in SQL SERVER 2014

Tags: sql-server, table

I am trying to create a duplicate table in SQL SERVER. I changed the table name but all other objects like constraints are same. Do i have to change all the objects as they exists in the base table or i can have same objects name?
I know it might sound a silly question but i am new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicitly named constraints must be uniquely named within a database.

If they are not unique, you'll see errors like this:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 10
>   There is already an object named 'PK_SomeTable' in the database.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 10
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

This is especially pertinent for creating #temp tables.  Never specify the name of a constraint when creating a #temp table, since concurrent executions of the code will fail with the above error.

Take for example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable
(
    ID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_SomeTable
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable2
(
    ID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_SomeTable
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);
```

The command fails because `PK_SomeTable` is defined twice, once in each table.  However, if we re-code the 2nd statement:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable2
(
    ID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_SomeTable2
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);
```

Now, it works.

For #temp tables, you'd use the following construct:

```
CREATE TABLE #SomeTable
(
    ID int NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);
```